# ¿Como desaparecer marcadores de Api google maps al alejarse con Zoom?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps, google-api

Tengo una aplicacion en la que tengo una marcador en cada estacion del Metro, Como se imaginan son muchas y al alejarme con Zoom se juntan todas y no me guta como se ven.

Asi que me preguntaba como podria hacer que mis marcadores desaparecieran dependiendo de cuanto zoom haya en la zona especifica, Esto lo hace google desde su aplicacion de Google Maps entonces creo que es posible.

a continuacion dejo 2 imagenes de lo que no quiero en mi app y luego otras 2 imagenes mostrando lo que hace google. Destaco que el tamaño de la imagen que coloco al marcador con .icon es de 32px

[image: En esta se muestran los marcadores a escala ciudad]

En esta se muestran los marcadores a escala ciudad como ven es tan grande que tapa las calles

[image: En esta se muestran los marcadores a escala pais]

En esta se muestran los marcadores a escala pais

[image: En esta captura de pantalla podemos ver que el marcador Nativitas es visible pero al alejarnos ocurre lo siguiente]

En esta captura de pantalla podemos ver que el marcador Nativitas es visible pero al alejarnos ocurre lo siguiente

[image: Al alejarnos a desaparecido el marcador nativitas]

Al alejarnos a desaparecido el marcador nativitas

Básicamente necesito hacer que mis marcadores desaparezcan cuando el usuario aleje la vista como con el ejemplo de el marcador Nativitas. De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nose que estas mostrando en la imagen del mapa de google, pero lo que buscas se llama Marker Clustering. Con esto los pines que queden muy juntos se mezclaran en uno solo con el numero que indica la cantidad de pines que se juntaron en ese pin.

No agrego el codigo porque hay muchas formas de implementacion.

Te dejo la documentacion oficial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering

Y un lindo tutorial que lamentablemente esta ingles:

http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/#markerclusterer